# UITap Gesture Does Not Display Photo Album

Tags: swift

I am trying to setup a UITapGesture, so that when the user taps the picture, it prompts to open their photo album and allows them to choose a photo. Here is my code:

```
Protocols 

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate {

 @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        // Hide the keyboard
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from 
their photo library.

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        //Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate  = self

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I've followed the Apple Documentation to no Avail, and also changed imagePickerController.source Type to .savedPhotosAlbum from .photoLibrary. However tapping the photo does not load the photo library, instead nothing happens.

Grateful if you can point out where I am going wrong, or what I am missing here?

Comment: Is this function getting called?

Comment: where you are setting up tap gesture ?

Comment: Post minimal version of the code that helps reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've added to gitHub Projects. Link here https://github.com/xrs3/tableViewProject.git    foodtracker is the broken project, and the other file is the working project. code appears to be exactly the same based on my comparison